# Generate HrefLang tag in Sitecore XMC pages

Tags: xm-cloud, urls

We need to create `hreflang` tag for the pages added to the site.

In the frontend, we are trying to build the page url for the current page. Is there any way, we can build the **page url** apart from `window.Location`. There is multisite environment.

If anyone have idea how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

`window.Location` is a decent way to get url but you can also use NextJs's router object to get route data.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();

const path = router.asPath;

//Just explore this router object, you will get lot of useful properties
```

And just an additional information -

```
import { getPublicUrl, LayoutServiceData } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';

const publicUrl = process.env.SITE_URL ?? getPublicUrl();
// This will give you public url
```

I have used a combination of above object to form desired urls.

Hope this helps !

Comment: thanks you this worked!